# check whether a point lies in a route - Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to highlight relevant locations in a google map when a user requests for a route.
I have found a few steps to implement. But got stuck at one point.

Let's assume that we have a collection of large number of points (a few thousands). We need to find out which of them lie in a (dynamic) route.

Step1: First filter out the points based on the route. That means, find the max-lat, min-lat, max-lon, min-lon of the route  and apply this filter out to our group. So that we can figure out a lesser number of eligible candidates.

Step2: We can still filter out the unnecessary points using a utility library called RouteBoxer. (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/routeboxer/1.0/examples/routeboxer-v3.html)

Step3: After above 2 steps, we have reduced the number of points to a few hundred from a few thousand. And these points would be somewhere around that route, though not exactly on it. This is where I face the challenge. How to check whether these points lie in that route? I dont think getting all the points a route and check the distance is a good solution (yeah, it will work. but..) as the route can be of any distance. Is there any way to check the minimum distance between a point and a route?

Comment: have you figured out a solution ? Please post your solution (code if possible) as I'm also doing something similar.

Comment: Just leaving my comment to keep updated. I'm looking for something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

RouteBoxer will give you a list of polygons or [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) (if if gives polygons you can get LatLngBounds fron it anyway). You can cycle through each of your points and check if that point lies on any of those bounds using the contains method of LatLngBounds class.

Comment: can you show some code to determine overlapping segments using RouterBox?

Comment: Can you detail "overlapping segments"?

Comment: See this site I made. (http://www.kbook.com.au/tb/) 

It lets you store multiple routes, and then you can browse them from the list in right. Browse already stored routes to see overlapped routes.

I need to determine how to find out overlapping routes or portion of route overlapping onto another route.

Comment: I'd probably generate two (rectangular) polygon objects containing tow routes, and then check if any of the the corner points of one polygon is inside the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is dijkstra or kruskal algorithm.